# npm: create script command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I run my NodeJs (ES6) project I type in the console the following:

```
./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js
```

Now I would like to add this command to the script section of package.json. So I did:

```
"scripts": {
    "run": "./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js"
},
```

Now when I run this I get:

```
$> npm run
Lifecycle scripts included in App:

run
   ./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js
```

And it doesn't run anything!

Why can't I do this?  For example, if I add my test command in there it does work

```
"scripts": {
    "test" : " ... ",
    ...
}
```

Any suggestions how I can add commands in there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run` is a registered npm command (command ro run Lifecycle scripts), so to execute your command you should call run twice:

```
npm run run
```

or use `start` instead:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/babel/bin/babel-node.js index.js"
},
```

And to start:

```
npm start
```

Comment: thnx, `start` is fine for me!